# Why sympathetic and parasympathetic nerves originate in different parts of CNS?

Tags: peripheral-nervous-system

Curious if there is a reason for having:

- parasympathetic nerves originating from brain stem and pelvic part of spinal cord
- sympathetic nerves originating from thoracic and lumbar parts

It looks well-organized, so maybe there is a good reason for that.