# Why are the sympathetic and parasympathetic axons different, in terms of presynaptic and postsynaptic length?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, neurophysiology

Does the parasympathetic system have a long presynaptic efferent axon because it takes a great distance to reach target organs from the brain stem or sacral region of the spine? Does the sympathetic have a long postsynaptic efferent axon (that reaches the target organ) since the presynaptic neurons are centrally located in the thoracic and lumbar regions of the spine? What purposes do these different axon lengths between the presynaptic and postsynaptic parasympathetic and sympathetic neurons serve? I'm looking for an answer that explains their benefits.

Comment: Seems similar to this question (also not answered): https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42168 :)

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this question?